# AADSTS500112: The reply address does not match the reply address provided when requesting Authorization code

Tags: azure-active-directory, react-aad-msal

I searched through the internet yet I couldn't find this specific problem.

AADSTS500112: The reply address 'http://localhost:3000/#/training' does not match the reply address 'http://localhost:3000/' provided when requesting Authorization code.

I am getting this error and my config in the app and the redirect uri is http://localhost:3000/#/training

I have no idea why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

According to
[Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#supported-schemes) ,

> When you try to use http scheme ,the port component (for example,
> :5001 or :443) is ignored for the purposes of matching a redirect URI.
> As a result, all of these URIs are considered equivalent.

For example , if you have more than one redirect uri for different purposes say http://localhost:5000/myapp and http://localhost:5001/myapp, both are considered equivalent and AAD may have configured for different application.
So mostly ,the redirect URL for web apps and services must begin with the https scheme . If you want to use the scheme http, you may try to use `http:\\localhost`  or by using different names in case of multiple redirect uris present with different ports.

If still issue persists you may raise a support request.

Comment: How can I test it on my local pc then? Any ideas? I am pretty beginner at Microsoft services

Comment: Can you please provide or edit the question with a screenshot of redirect uris present in azure AD portal in app registration>authentication blade

Comment: my url was set to http://localhost:3000/#/training, anyways I stop looking for solutions for now. I put the msal provider on top now and I get my access code when the app loads and store it on the session storage to retrieve access token. This approach solves my case.